# Postgres @sqlupdate casting data type

Tags: postgresql, casting, dao

I have a quick question to ask for help.

In my Postgres table "user_profile" I have following "video_uploaded" column defined as

```
    id                     | character(19)
    videos_uploaded        | character(19)[]             |
```

which stores the video ids (fixed length with 19 characters).

When I wrote `@SqlUpdate` using `array_append` function in  DAO interface like following

```
    @SqlUpdate("UPDATE user_profile set videos_uploaded = array_append(videos_uploaded, :vid) where id = :id")

    void appendVideoToUpload(@Bind("id") String id, @Bind("vid") String vid);
```

the program always throw following exception

> ERROR: function array_append(character[], character varying) does not exist
>   !   Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

seems to ask for adding explicit type casts, I then add casting like

```
array_append(videos_uploaded::varchar[], :vid::varchar)
```

but similar exception still happens. Can anyone familiar with the issue gives some quick help? Thanks!

Roy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Char and varchar are different datatypes, so functions that take `anyarray, anyelement` will fail. Both parameters must be the same type, so you can try either

```
= array_append(videos_uploaded::varchar[], :vid)::char(19)[]
```

or

```
= array_append(videos_uploaded, (:vid)::char(19))
```

If your software has trouble with parameters and double-colon casting (which is likely since the parameters are colon-based rather than question mark-based (`?`) use CAST instead:

```
= CAST(array_append(CAST(videos_uploaded AS varchar[]), :vid) AS char(19)[])
```

or

```
= array_append(videos_uploaded, CAST(:vid AS char(19)))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Tried both options, but still failed. The error message says "no named parameter matches "char" and no positional param for place 1 has been set. The difficult part seems to parse vid in array_append(...) as a char(19) element.

Comment: That's an error from your software having difficulty with the PostgreSQL-style for casting using double colon (value::type). Use `CAST(value AS type)` instead and it will work.

Comment: @R.Zheng I've updated the reply with examples using CAST

Comment: Hi Ziggy, this is  great! I just tried explicit CAST and it works! Thanks a lot and really appreciate.